# Writing a NSPredicate for my scenario

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a predicate and i need to filter out an attribute. The name of the attribute is `location`, and this attribute could have `none`, `one` of `more` values. So how could i write the predicate

for example if the hospital location could have 0 or more values. It could have no location, or 1 (New York) or more (New York, California, Texas ). So based on the values on the array how could i write the predicate.

```
NSArray *filteredHospitalArr= [hospitalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"location= %@ ", [hospitalObject objectAtIndexPath:0]]]; // ???
```

<-- Say at this instance we have 3 locations for this Hospital Location. How can i write this predicate.

Also note, that the number of location might change, (it might have none, one or more values)

EDIT:

Say if the user is asked to choose his/her filter criteria for a particular hospital. He/she would select one or more locations. So how do i write the predicate to suit his/her filter requirement. (The user might or might not enter a filter criteria, or enter more than one preferred location). So how could i write it based on this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to filter out hospitals with no locations?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"locations.@count != 0"]
```

update: maybe something more like

```
@"ANY locations IN %@", myArrayOfLocations"
```

Comment: Yes i do, i need to filter the location (s) according to the users preference(s)

Comment: Something like `NSArray *filteredHospitalArr= [hospitalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY locations IN  %@ ", userPreferenceArray]];` ?

Comment: if userPreferenceArray contains locations

Comment: Yes it is an Array, and contains String locations. @"New York" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Apple Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) can help you?